# It is possible to mask a Image Texture with Emission?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

It is possible to mask a Image Texture with Emission on Blender, like adding soft borders or something and being able to control them, without having the need or external softwares?

As you can see, i have an image on my Render (The Sun, middle one), and i need to control the borders since are too hard and i do need a mask.
[image]

Comment: can you show an example of what you are after?

Comment: Ok, i uploaded an image.

Comment: I'll show you how to do it. Could you please upload a link to the image you're using.

Comment: I uploaded the PNG image here:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/1qat28a7j06d7cd/Sol_Mas_Luz__00000.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using a spherical gradient texture with a mix node:

[image]

Though any mask texture you like can be used in place of the gradient.

Answer (score 3):

Set up the nodes as pictured below to achieve it. Just use a ***Gradient Texture*** as a mask. Set its type to ***Quadratic Sphere***.

[image]

Comment: Oops, I guess I'm a bit late. You won @gandalf3. As usual ;).

Comment: Haha, we even came up with identical node setups XD

Answer (score 1):

- Use the Blender compositor for the sun image only. Use a color ramp to select the brightest colors of the sun. The final result can have alpha transparency and be png.  The result can be put back into a 3D View.
- You can use a white circle image to absolutely include the center if that suits your needs.  Thus the color ramp can be more finely tuned to the corona or rays of the sun.
- If the sun rays are excessively close to the edge consider particle systems or elongated rectangles with more manageable transparency.  You could have a radial gradient to become the alpha channel.  There is no guarantee the image you show will be easy to manipulate at the borders of the rectangle.